# Display Laravel 5 validation errors in Angularjs 1.3

Tags: json, angularjs, validation, laravel-5

I am a newbie to Laravel 5 and angularjs. I am working on a project which uses laravel 5 as backend and angularjs as front-end. I am utilizing laravel 5 for RESTful api routes which are accessed by angularjs front-end.

I have worked out a solution for capturing the laravel 5 form validation errors and displaying it in angularjs front end as below.

My question is: Is this an acceptable way of working? Or there is a better approach to achieve this?

My code:

In **Laravel 5**:
1. I am doing form validations through a dedicated request class. For eg for a create page form I have a PageRequest class in `app\requests` folder with the following code:

```
class PageRequest extends Request {

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    //any authorized user validations here..
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'menuName' => 'required | min:5 | max:50',
        'position' => 'required',
        'visible'  => 'required'
    ];
}
```

}
2. Next in my PagesController which provides the methods for RESTful api, for example the create Page form will post back to the `store` method in the `PagesController` which can be as follows:

```
class PagesController extends BaseController{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param PageRequest $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(PageRequest $request)
    {
        $request['slug'] =$request['menuName'];
        return $this->page->create($request->all()) ? json_encode(['success'=>'true']) : json_encode($request->messages());
    }
}
```

3. Then in my angular content.js file which defines the ui-router  states with controllers, I have the following snippet to handle the create page:

```
.state('content.subjects.pages.create',{
            url:'/create',
            views:{
                'forms@content.subjects':{
                    templateUrl:'/partials/create-page.html',
                    controller:['$scope', '$stateParams','$state', 'Subject', 'Page',
                    function($scope, $stateParams, $state, Subject, Page){
                        $scope.subject = {};
                        $scope.pages={};
                        $scope.messages={}; //place holder for the error messages
                        Subject.edit($stateParams.subjectSlug).success(function(data){
                           $scope.subject = data;
                        });
                        Subject.pages($stateParams.subjectSlug).success(function(data){
                            $scope.pages = data;
                        });
                        $scope.subject_id = $scope.subject.id;
                        $scope.submitPage = function(){
                            $scope.pageData['subject_id'] = $scope.subject.id;
                            Page.save($scope.pageData).success(function(data){
                                $scope.pages.push($scope.pageData);
                                $state.go('content.subjects.pages', {subjectSlug:$scope.subject.slug});
                            }).error(function(data){
                                //if the validation in laravel fails it will return the $request->messages as json
                                // we assign it to the $scope.messages object
                               $scope.messages = data;
                            });
                        };
                    }]
                }
            }
        })
```

4. And finally in the create-pages.html partial I am able to reference the $scope.messages as :

```
<div class="row page create-form" >
<!--<div id="messages" ng-show="message">{{ message }}</div>-->
<form class="form-horizontal create page" role="form" data-ng-submit="submitPage()">
    <h4 class="form-title">Create New Page</h4>
    <div class="form-group menuName">
        <div class="input-group has-feedback" data-ng-class="{'has-error':errorMenuName}">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Page Name</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control menuName" name="menuName" data-ng-model="pageData.menuName"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger">{{messages['menuName']}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group position">
        <div class="input-group has-feedback" data-ng-class="{'has-error':errorPosition}">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Position</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control position" name="position" data-ng-model="pageData.position"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback">}</span>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger">{{messages['position'][0]}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group visible">
        <div class="input-group has-feedback" data-ng-class="{'has-error':errorVisible}">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Published</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control visible" name="visible" data-ng-model="pageData.visible"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="text-danger">{{messages['visible'][0]}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group layout">
        <div class="input-group hidden has-feedback" data-ng-class="{'has-error':errorLayout}">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Page Layout</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control layout" name="layout" data-ng-model="pageData.layout"/>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-action create">
        <div class="btn-container create">
            <button class="btn btn-formIcon" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Create</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Any suggestions for a better approach will be appreciated.